# How to store the content of a listview row in a SQL database with C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program that updates an Audit Trail (a listview) when something happens, like a user login, create/delete a new user and so on.

The listview has 10 columns like: Date, Time, Message Description, Event type and so on.

I need to store each listview entry (subItems of a raw) in a SQL database whenever I update the listView with new subItems. I couldn't find a listView `ItemsChanged` event, so I used the `ItemSelectionChanged` event. But how can I copy these data into the database at each `ItemSelectionChanged` event?

Please help

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Where do the updates come from? Usually you update a database when something happens (user login/create/delete) and find a way to update your user interface (listview) accordingly. How would a listview know when a user logs in?

Comment: I am using C# 2013. When a user logs in, I update the listview: Date, time, message user login... When i update the listview, I also select the item so that when I update it with new details, it can raise an ItemSelectionChanged event. When this event is raised, I want to copy the subItems in the listView row into database for future reporting. The problem, i can't seem to succeed in copying each subItem in a selected row. I can i do this? How can i get the individual subItem of a selected row, so that i can copy them into my SQL database table?

Comment: @RonaldWildenberg I insert the updates manually. I have a function to update the listview that i call each time i have done something that needs to be reported. After i update the listview, i select the item so that when i will update again it can raise an ItemSelectionChanged event. It's in this event that i want to copy the row of data into a database. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make insert/update when a new row is added/changed.

1. get a reference to a new row thru event args.
2. row has a `SubItems` property.
3. check whether each `subitem` has a `Name` property set otherwise you'll get `NullReferenceException`.
4. build your insert/update query using references to those subitems values:

   ```
   cmd.CommandText = "insert into CustomTable(title, price) values(@title, @price)";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", row.SubItems["title"]);
   // apply all necessary conversions
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", row.SubItems["price"]);
   ```
5. you got the point)
6. good luck!